# Is there an isomorphism $\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(A,A),A)\cong A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Viewing $A$ as an $A$-module, is there an isomorphism $\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(A,A),A)\cong A$? Here is my attempt, first, I define a map in $\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(A,A),A)$ by $g_{x}(f)=f(x)$. Then I define a map $\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(\textrm{Hom}_{A-mod}(A,A),A)\rightarrow A$ by $g_{x}\mapsto x$, which is unfortunately not well-defined.

Comment: If $A$ is also unitary, then we have an isomorphism of $A$-modules $$ A \rightarrow Hom_{A-mod}(A,A), a \mapsto (x \mapsto ax) $$ with inverse $$ Hom_{A-mod}(A,A) \rightarrow A, \varphi \mapsto \varphi(1).$$ Then we can apply this isomorphism twice to get the desired isomorphism $$  Hom_{A-mod}( Hom_{A-mod}(A,A) ,A) \cong  Hom_{A-mod}(A,A)  \cong A.  $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's step back and look at the big picture.

For any $A$-module $M$, we can form an $A$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$. This construction has a nice property: any isomorphism $N \cong M$ gives rise to an isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(N,A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$. Important and good exercise: prove this!

So, let's define $F(A)$ to mean $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$. By the above, $F(N) \cong F(M)$ whenever $N \cong M$.

In this question, we are wondering: is $F(F(A))$ isomorphic to $A$?

Well, it would sure be convenient if $F(A)$ was isomorphic to $A$. Then $F(A) \cong A$ would imply $F(F(A)) \cong F(A) \cong A$, as desired!

Indeed, $F(A) = \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,A)$ is isomorphic to $A$. Why should this be true? Well, let's consider the example $A = \mathbb{R}$. We totally understand $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$; this is just the ring of $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. By basic linear algebra, any $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is of the form $x \mapsto \alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and it follows that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$. So, we should try to explicitly write down this isomorphism, and then try to translate its construction (and the proof that it is an isomorphism) to the more general setting of $A$-modules. I'll leave that part up to you.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether it also work if $A$ is not unitary? My guess would be that it still holds true. However, I wouldn't know how to prove that the map $\alpha \mapsto (x \mapsto \alpha x)$ is surjective (clearly in the unitary case, the inverse map is given by the evaluation at $1$ and hence it is surjective).

Comment: In the non-unital case this map is never surjective, since the identity endomorphism will not be in the image. If $x \mapsto \alpha x : A \to A$ is the identity map, then $\alpha$ is a multiplicative identity in $A$! Even abstractly, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,A)$ can fail to be isomorphic to $A$. For example, let $A$ be $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ under the zero product. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,A)$ has 16 elements, but $A$ has only 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course, I cannot produce the identity endomorphism... should have thought a bit harder about it.